# AS3 validate form fields?

Tags: actionscript-3, validation, field

I wrote a AS3 script, i have 2 fields to validate, i.e email and name.

For email i use:

```
function isValidEmail(Email:String):Boolean {
    var emailExpression:RegExp = /^[a-z][\w.-]+@\w[\w.-]+\.[\w.-]*[a-z][a-z]$/i;    
    return emailExpression.test(Email); 
}
```

How about name field? Can you show me some sample code?

EDIT:

Invalid are:

- blank
- between 4 - 20 characters
- Alphanumeric only(special characters not allowed)
- Must start with alphabet

Comment: i think it depends on what do you think a valid name is?

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want a function like this:

```
function isNameValid(firstname:String):Boolean
{
    var nameEx:RegExp = /^([a-zA-Z])([ \u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z']){4,20}+$/;
    return nameEx.test(firstname);
}
```

Rundown of that regular expression:

- **[a-zA-Z]**  - Checks if first char is a normal letter.
- **[ \u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z']** - Checks if all other chars are unicode characters or a space. So names like "*Mc'Neelan*" will work.
- **{4,20}** - Makes sure the name is between 4 and 20 chars in length.

You can remove the space at the start of the middle part if you don't want spaces.

Hope this helps. here are my references:

- [Regular expression validate name asp.net using RegularExpressionValidator](http://carlosrivero.com/regular-expression-validate-name-asp-net-using-regularexpressionvalidator)
- [Java - Regular Expressions: Validate Name](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Network-Remote/RegularExpressionsValidateName.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
function isNameValid(firstname:String):Boolean
{
    var nameEx:RegExp = /^([a-zA-Z])([ \u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z']){4,20}+$/;
    return nameEx.test(firstname);
}


{4,20} instead {2,20}
Problem avoided for names like Ajit
```